# Protractor/Js - Unable to get accurate table row and column count

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, protractor

I am trying to verify the number of rows and columns in a table using Protractor/Js.

I have tried the following **four** functions but I am returned in-accurate results. I believe my locator might be wrong - **'.tsc_table_s13'**

Rows:

```
 $(locator).all(by.xpath('.//tbody/tr')).count().then(function (data) {
            expect(data).to.equal(parseInt(myCount));
        });
```

Or...

```
var table = element.all(by.css(locator));
        table.all(by.tagName("tr")).count().then(function (data) {
            expect(data).to.equal(parseInt(mycount));
        });
```

Columns:

```
$(locator).all(by.xpath('.//tbody/tr/td')).count().then(function (data) {
            expect(data).to.equal(parseInt(myCount));
        });
```

Or...

```
var table = element.all(by.css(locator));
        table.all(by.tagName("td")).count().then(function (data) {
            expect(data).to.equal(parseInt(myCount));
        });
```

When I test the column count, 25 (or 26) is returned and I expect only 6.
When I test row count, 0 is returned when I expect 4.
The table can be found here - http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple solution
     //test.spec.js

```
 describe('all rows and columns', function() {
   var rows;
   var cols;
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  browser.get('http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-table/');

  rows = element.all(by.xpath('.//tbody/tr'));
  cols=element.all(by.xpath('.//tbody/tr[1]/td'));
}); 

it('should list row and column counts', function() {
  //expect(rows.count()).toEqual(4);
  //expect(cols.count()).toEqual(6);
  rows.count().then(function(cnt) {
  console.log(cnt);
  })
  cols.count().then(function(cnt) {
  console.log(cnt);       
   })
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

count that is return is correct because if you manually test the locator inside chrome you will see the same result.

first you get the result from locator .tsc_table_s13 and ontop of it concatenate new locator.

attaching results
[image]
[image]